# Extract src from image Tag

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have an image Tag like

```
<img src="abc" height="20" width="50" />
```

How can I extract only the source from it in php?

Comment: You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. They are not up to the task. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way would be to use regular expressions.

```
<?php
$tag='<img src="abc" height="20" width="50" />';
$extracted=preg_replace('/<img [^>]*src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/','\\1',$tag);
echo $extracted;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use SimpleXML very quickly here:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('<img src="abc" height="20" width="50" />');
$src = (string) $sxe['src'];
```